# Can't install sail.js error

Tags: sails.js

when I install the sailsjs. I got an error.I used npm install sails.I got console.log debug error .Can anyone tell me the error.Thankyou!.[image]

Comment: dont add screenshots of error..add error logs in the question itself. Also describe your problem in more details..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and retry the installation.